# How to Detect The Order Number of Selected Option by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please let me know that how I can detect the order number of Selected option from the list dropdown?

```js
  $('#items').on( 'change', function() {
      var index = $( "#items option:selected" ).eq();
      console.log(index);

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="items">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $('#items').on( 'change', function() {

   $('#items option').each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).is(':selected')) {
   alert(index)
   }

  });
})
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Y2aDP/280/

Comment: Sure, take my answer. :)

Comment: Sorry, I really didn't. I was playing on the fiddle and added it to mine, but I did upvote yours

Answer (score 3):

One line to get the index

```
var index = $('#items option:selected').index();
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
function getIndex() {
    var i = 0;
    var r = 0;
    $("#items option").each(function() {
        i++;
        if($(this).is(':selected'))
            r = i;

    });
    return r;
}

$('#items').on( 'change', function() {
    console.log(getIndex());
});
```